# Change BadgeDrawable Typeface in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-styles, material-components-android

I need to use a custom font for `BadgeDrawable` appears on top of my bottom navigation bar item. So I created a custom style for badge like this:

```
<style name="CustomBadge" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Badge">
    <item name="badgeGravity">BOTTOM_END</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">@font/custom_font</item>
</style>
```

and applied it to my default app style using this line:

```
<item name="badgeStyle">@style/CustomBadge</item>
```

although the `badgeGravity` part works fine as I'm seeing the change, the `android:typeface` is not working at all. I also tried `font` and `fontFamily` (with and without `android:` prefix) but they don't work either.
I'm using this version of material library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to change `TextAppearance` style

instead of

```
<item name="android:typeface">@font/custom_font</item>
```

put

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">TextAppearanceCustom.Badge</style>
```

and create some style like below

```
<style name="TextAppearanceCustom.Badge" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Badge">
    <item name="android:typeface">@font/custom_font</item>
</style>
```

check out all available options in [original file](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/badge/res/values/styles.xml)

Comment: Your answer makes sense to work, but I have no idea why it does not

Comment: There is also an issue about this problem here https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/471

Comment: well, thats sad... looks like this bug is there for some time... :/